# Plot areas of high occupancy as a densitymap or contour in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I have an image with several points and  I labeled them so I can know their coordinates (x,y).
Now I have a list of coordinates such as:

```
obj [0]: (1.5918367346938775, 806.42857142857144)
obj [1]: (5.5131578947368425, 860.59539473684208)
obj [2]: (0.0, 853.0)
(...)
obj [1183]: (1722.6078431372548, 1575.8725490196077)
obj [1184]: (1725.7272727272727, 330.72727272727275)
obj [1185]: (1726.4285714285713, 335.85714285714283)
obj [1186]: (1727.0, 327.0)
```

Having a large dataset of (x,y) point positions I would like to plot areas of high occupancy as a densitymap or contour in Python.

I used matplotlib's contour, but it does not give me good information about the density:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

z = th1
plt.subplot(2,2,1),plt.contour(np.transpose(z))
plt.title('Basic Contour')[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Have you tried `matplotlib`'s [`contour`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/griddata_demo.html)?

Comment: yes I did. However it does not give me much of information...:    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    z = th1
    plt.subplot(2,2,1),plt.contour(np.transpose(z))
plt.title('Basic Contour')"""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to estimate the density is to use the `matplotlib.tri.Triangulation` class that connects points using triangles, and then compute the area of each triangle with an analytic formula based on coordinates. Then the density can be deduced from the inverse of each triangle surface.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import (tripcolor, triplot, scatter,
    show, title, savefig, colorbar)
from matplotlib.tri import Triangulation, TriAnalyzer

# Coordinates
x = np.random.random(100)
y = np.random.random(100)

# Triangulation
tri = Triangulation(x, y)

# Remove flat triangles
mask = TriAnalyzer(tri).get_flat_tri_mask(0.01)
tri.set_mask(mask)

# Coordinates of the edges
ii1, ii2, ii3 = tri.triangles.T
x1 = x[ii1] ; y1 = y[ii1]
x2 = x[ii2] ; y2 = y[ii2]
x3 = x[ii3] ; y3 = y[ii3]

# Surfaces
surf = 0.5*np.abs((x2-x1)*(y3-y1)-(x3-x1)*(y2-y1))

# Density
dens = 1/(surf*3) # 3 points per triangle!

# Plot
xd = (x1+x2+x3)/3.
yd = (y1+y2+y3)/3.
tripcolor(xd, yd, dens, cmap='cool')
colorbar()
triplot(tri, color='k', linewidth=0.3)
scatter(x,y)
title('Density')
savefig('density.png')
show()
```

[image: Density of points]

Comment: is it possible to do it by calculating the average distance to the closests 3 points and then estimating the density based on this avergae distance?

Comment: I would say that the estimate if density must clearly integrate the notion of surface, not only distance. In this case, it must be considered constant inside a triangle. So, take a point (like on a grid), search for the triangle (TriFinder I think), compute the density using the triangle surface. You can smooth your result by considering neighbouring triangles also, or just applying a filter to your gridded results, or both!

Comment: Could you explain me better (with some comments) your code? I am new with Python an I am having some troubles understanding everything you did (thank you so much for your time! )

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried binning them in histograms?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coords = np.random.normal(0, 1, (2, 1000))

H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(coords[0], coords[1], bins=50)

im = plt.imshow(H, interpolation='nearest', origin='low',
                extent=[xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]])
```

Comment: I wanted something like this but without the normal approximation of the data...:`import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu, sigma = 0, 0.1
x = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1186)
y = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1186)

xy = np.vstack([x,y])
density = stats.gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)

idx = density.argsort()
x, y, density = x[idx], y[idx], density[idx]
plt.subplot(2,2,3), plt.scatter(x, y, c=density)
plt.title('Contour')

plt.show()`                                                        @fjarri and @Greg